# Why did the First Mexican Empire replace 60% of its Regency?

Tags: government, mexico, individuals

From September of 1821 until Agustín I ascended the throne, a five-man Imperial Regency governed independent Mexico. Initially it included [Agustín Iturbide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agust%C3%ADn_de_Iturbide) (the same), [José Isidro Yáñez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Isidro_Y%C3%A1%C3%B1ez), [Manuel Bárcena](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_de_la_B%C3%A1rcena), Manuel Velázquez, and [Juan O'Donojú](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_O%27Donoj%C3%BA), who dying soon thereafter, was replaced by bishop [José Antonio Pérez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Joaqu%C3%ADn_P%C3%A9rez_Mart%C3%ADnez). In April of 1822, the last three regency seats were reassigned to [Conde de Heras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_de_Heras_Soto), [Nicolás Bravo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicol%C3%A1s_Bravo), and [Miguel Valentín](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_Valent%C3%ADn_y_Tamayo). (This is due to *The Mexican Empire of Iturbide* by Timothy Anna, pp. 37, 56.) The high clergy thus went from two to zero seats on the regency, though Iturbide was very pro-clergy.

Why, after six months, did the composition of the regency change so dramatically?

Comment: I included links to the English Wikipedia where they existed, and otherwise gave the Spanish ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question seems to imply that the Regency membership was under the influence or control of Iturbide, but according to Bancroft, at this later time these seats were reorganized ***by the Congress***, who were in ongoing conflict with Iturbide,   essentially attempting to stack it *against* Iturbide. From Bancroft, [History of Mexico 1804-1822](https://books.google.com/books?id=MfdAAAAAIAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=inauthor%3A%22Hubert%20Howe%20Bancroft%22%20mexico&pg=PA769#v=onepage&q&f=false), pg 769 (emphasis mine).

> As for the congress its hostility toward him was now openly expressed.
>   By decree of the 11th of April the regency was reorganized the bishop
>   of Puebla Manuel de la Bárcena and Velazquez de Leon **who were too
>   evidently subservient to Iturbide being removed from their positions**
>   and their places supplied by the conde de Casa de Heras Soto, Doctor
>   Miguel Valentin and Nicolás Bravo in whom the congress placed the
>   utmost confidence. Yañez was retained in his seat for the reason of
>   Iturbide's known enmity to him.

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agust%C3%ADn_de_Iturbide#Emperor_Agust%C3%ADn_I) has a paragraph concerning this conflict between Iturbide and the congress for a little more background to the situation:

> In the meantime, the governing junta that Iturbide headed convened a
>   constituent congress to set up the new government. The new government
>   had indirect representation, based on the Cadiz model, but the Plan of
>   Iguala and the Treaty of Córdoba were clear that the order of things
>   would be kept as it had been before the Cadiz Constitution. Thus,
>   Iturbide and the junta declared that they would not be bound by the
>   Cadiz Constitution but kept the Congress that was convened.[12] That
>   led to division, which came to a head in February 1822. In its
>   inauguration, Congress swore that it would never abide for all of the
>   powers of the state to fall into the hands of a single person or
>   entity. It, however, proceeded to assign sovereignty to itself, rather
>   than to the people, and proclaimed that it held all three powers of
>   the State. It also considered lowering military pay and decreasing the
>   size of the army. Those moves threatened to reduce Iturbide's
>   influence in current and future governments.

Iturbide assumed the role of Emperor a month later, and [dissolved this congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agust%C3%ADn_de_Iturbide#Dissolution_of_Congress) in October:

> Iturbide closed down the Congress on 31 October 1822 and created a new
>   junta, the National Institutional Junta, to legislate in its place two
>   days later, answering only to himself.

Comment: Aha, it makes sense that conflict between Iturbide and the Congress played out in the reorganization of the Regency. After dismissing Congress, he was forced to restore it. Thanks!